# How to load missing system symbol files in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-5

I'm trying to trace into some .NET 5 code.  Following recommendations found elsewhere, I've enabled the "Enable .NET Framework Source Stepping" and "Enable Source Server Support" options, I've checked the Microsoft Symbol Server checkbox as a symbol source.

Upon running the program, symbols load for many, but not all of the assemblies.  Among others, I don't get any symbols for System.Data.Common, which I currently have a need to trace into.

Does anyone know why I'm missing symbols for about half the system assemblies and how to gain access to them?

Comment: Have you tried manually loading the symbols (using the modules window)?

Comment: @PMF Tried that.  It opens up an Open File dialog and asks for the location of the PDB file... which I don't have because VS didn't download it from the symbol server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test with a dummy project and it seems that some assemblies PDBs stored in the MS Symbols server `doesn't match image`.

You can double check by reading log of the PDB loading phase. It's quite simple.

Open Debug Modules Windows and find your assembly. Than

[image]

In my test I got

[image]

Maybe an issue in .NET Core building process? It seems that the PDB file is not related to the dll file...

It worth an issue on .NET Core project.

Comment: Thanks!  I've opened an issue for this. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60123